# How to use regular expression to extract bit in middle of a string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Using PHP PCRE regular expressions I want to extract the centre part of a string where the parts either side may or may not occur. I.e.

```
n bedroom property type in some town
```

I want to extract 'property type' using one regular expression. I do not know all the possibilities for property type but what is consistent is the start bit (its always '\d bedroom') and the end bit (its always 'in some town'). Also, either the start or end bits (or both) may not be present.

I.e. the subject strings could be one of ...

```
6 bedroom ground floor flat in Edinburgh

house in Manchester

3 bedroom apartment
```

So want to extract 'ground floor flat', 'house', and 'apartment' respectively.

Something like this (which doesn't quite work)....

```
(\s*\d+\s+bedrooms?\s*)?(.*?)(\s+in)?
```

Comment: "respectively with one regular expression." --- why do you want one ugly and complex regex instead of having several simple and easy to maintain ones?

Comment: I cant write arbitrary PHP code as its part of a framework. The regular expression feeds into a parser that only accepts one regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add anchors to your regex and declare first ant last group to be not captured:

```
/^(?:\s*\d+\s+bedrooms?\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s+in\s.*)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

This `#(((?<bedroomCount>\d+)\s+bedroom)\s+)?(?<type>.+?)\s(in\s+(?<city>\w+))?\n#i` works I think but you need an extra newline ad the end of the testing string.

An example [here](http://pastie.org/2589437)

Comment: Thanks 3on, but I cant get it to work. I cant figure out what type of regExp this is: (?<bedroomCount>

Comment: `(?<myVarName>` this a way to give names to your matches, it makes it easier to use them later on. Not all php version supports it.